# Em uma arquitetura orientada por serviços, o banco de dados é descentralizado?

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software, services

Estou com a perspectiva de pegar um projeto grande, e pela sua própria escala sugeri a adoção de uma [arquitetura orientada por serviços](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) - pois é mais fácil resolver vários problemas médios do que um muito grande. Fui questionado em relação ao banco de dados: que mesmo que a aplicação seja dividida em componentes modulares, o banco deveria ser projetado **inteiro** *a priori*. Isso me soou estranho, mas pela minha falta de experiência com esse paradigma não soube argumentar a respeito.

É do meu entendimento que cada serviço deve ser pouco acoplado ([*loosely coupled*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loosely_coupled)) aos demais para justificar essa abordagem. E meu senso comum diz que - se não está acoplado - não precisa estar no mesmo banco, mesmo porque assim fica mais fácil de crescer em escala (colocar cada sub-sistema em um servidor distinto, por exemplo).

Isso implica, é claro, em perder um pouco da integridade referencial - pois nos poucos pontos em que um sub-sistema interage com outro, temos entidades em comum entre eles. Na minha opinião, isso não é um grande problema, mas essa é a principal preocupação de quem me questionou, insistindo que somente com um banco de dados unificado se pode manter a consistência dos dados.

Qual dessas duas abordagens é a mais comum nos sistemas que seguem a SOA? Por que? E como é resolvido o problema:

- da consistência de dados, se a resposta for "distribuído"?
- da modularização/crescimento em escala, se a resposta for "centralizado"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idealmente, o banco deve ser abstraído.

Estou supondo um caso no qual o "banco" guarda uma massa de dados que pertence e diz respeito exclusivamente ao sistema que abrange os próprios serviços. Tanto faz se é centralizado ou não, todos os serviços que forem acessá-lo devem fazer isso pelos mesmos endpoints/URI's. Para eles deve ser transparente (i.e.: deve ser irrelevante) se o banco é centralizado ou descentralizado. Isso inclusive diminui o acoplamento, pois facilita substituir uma base de dados por outra.

Agora, se você fala em distribuição ao dar uma base de dados completamente separada para cada serviço... Isso vale a pena se cada serviço funcionar em um domínio (domínio de conceito/sistema, não de URL) diferente. Isso é comum quando você integra seu sistema com sistemas de terceiros. Por exemplo, se você quer fazer uma aplicação que diz onde os seus amigos estão, não há problema (conceitual) em usar a base do Facebook para amigos e a base do Google para mapas.

Comment: Quando eu digo "distribuído" eu não me refiro *necessariamente* a eles estarem em bases distintas. Por exemplo, se a tabela A não está ligada nem direta nem indiretamente à tabela B, então tanto faz se estão na mesma base ou não. Por outro lado, se A tem uma chave estrangeira pra B, então elas precisam estar na mesma base - mesmo que os serviços que as acessam sejam capazes de isoladamente fazer cada um o seu trabalho. Pelo que eu entendi da sua resposta, é irrelevante se está modelado de um ou outro jeito, pois há uma camada de abstração entre o serviço e os dados que ele acessa. É isso?

Comment: Exato. Essa camada facilita a mudança de base, não só para mudanças de provedor (i.e.: trocar MySQL por Oracle) quanto para mudar o ambiente (fazer o código apontar para a base de testes ou produção facilmente e sob demanda). Se você abstrair o banco, os serviços não precisam saber se ele é distribuído ou não. Daí você o modela sem dores de cabeça.

Comment: Em tempo: bancos modernos são feitos pra funcionar muito bem em cluster - se você considerar isso uma forma de distribuição!

Comment: Eu concordo com o Renan de que o banco deve ser abstraído. A questão da distribuição nesse caso é mais "funcional" (ou de "propriedade") do que de armazenamento e normalização. Dizer que serviços são isolados tem mais o sentido de que eles são auto-suficientes (se um serviço devolve um código de cliente, por exemplo, é um código interno *dele* - independentemente do chamador armazenar esse valor ou não). Aliás, provavelmente vai ficar mais fácil entender e discutir se você fornecer um exemplo simples do domínio do problema.

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu não tenho como dar exemplos, pois o projeto ainda está na fase de "sondagem". O que eu tenho é uma lista de abrangências (tipo: "Gestão de Canteiros de Obras", "Gestão de Empreiteiros e Medições", "Gestão Ambiental", etc) que - no meu entendimento - correspondem a sub-sistemas com um alto grau de independência entre eles. Ainda que eles se refiram a uma entidade comum do mundo real (ex.: uma obra) eu entendo que toda forma de integração entre os serviços deva se dar exclusivamente via sua interface de serviço, sem expor detalhes internos (ex.: o id da obra no BD).

Comment: De todo modo, eu estou satisfeito com essa resposta. Após digerir um pouco as informações, principalmente à luz desse último exemplo (pois eu devo pensar num serviço não importando se ele é externo ou interno, não é essa a ideia do SOA?), eu creio ter encontrado a solução pras minhas dúvidas.